# Why does my neural net identify everything as person or background for a semantic segmentation task?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

Firstly, I am newbie to these topics. My neural network classifies everything as **person** or **background** on both training and validation sets. Training set is **VOC2011**.

https://github.com/JihongJu/keras-fcn

```
#Defining model
from keras_fcn import FCN
fcn_vgg16 = FCN(input_shape=(500, 500, 3), classes=21)
fcn_vgg16.load_weights('fcn_vgg16_weights.h5')


#Preprocessing to image
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np
​
img_path = 'catdog2.jpg'
img1 = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(500, 500))
x = image.img_to_array(img1)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
#x = preprocess_input(x)

predicted = fcn_vgg16.predict(x)

predicted = np.squeeze(predicted, axis=0)


#I may have completely misunderstood the visualization part
color_list = {0:[176, 23,  31],  1:[220, 20,  60],  2:[139,  71,  93],  3:[0,     9, 236],  3:[255,  20, 147], 
              4:[139,  0, 139],  5:[0,    0, 255],  6:[202, 225, 255],  7:[30,  144, 255],  8:[240, 248, 255],
              9:[0,  245, 255], 10:[0,  199, 140], 11:[0,   255, 127], 12:[139, 131, 134], 13:[255, 255,   0],
             14:[255,165,   0], 15:[255, 153, 18], 16:[255,  69,   0], 17:[255,   0,   0], 18:[0,     0,   0],
             19:[219,219, 219], 20:[0,  245, 255],255:[0,     0, 205]}
#*15:[255, 153, 18] => Orange*


"""
{0: 'background',
 1: 'aeroplane',
 2: 'bicycle',
 3: 'bird',
 4: 'boat',
 5: 'bottle',
 6: 'bus',
 7: 'car',
 8: 'cat',
 9: 'chair',
 10: 'cow',
 11: 'diningtable',
 12: 'dog',
 13: 'horse',
 14: 'motorbike',
 15: 'person',
 16: 'potted-plant',
 17: 'sheep',
 18: 'sofa',
 19: 'train',
 20: 'tv/monitor',
 255: 'ambigious'}
 """

#http://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2017/01/23/fully-convolutional-networks-(fcns)-for-image-segmentation/


import scipy.misc as smp
#Create a 500x500x3 array of 8 bit unsigned integers
data = np.zeros((500, 500, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
​
for i in range(500):
    for j in range(500):
        data[i][j] = color_list[np.argmax(predicted[i][j])]

img2 = smp.toimage(data)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
ax1.imshow(np.squeeze(img1, axis=0))
ax2.imshow(img2)
plt.show()
```

[image: Here is the result (orange means person)]

[image: Without preprocessing to image]

[image: With human and non human segmentation]

[image: 100 epochs result]

Is that a kind of **local minima (or saddle point?)** that predicts everything as background (the most frequent label)?

What is the reason, what are your ideas?
And also is there any proper way for visualization of semantic segmentation?

I guess there is something wrong about training. If there is **overfitting**, losses have always decreased, why is the result the same for traning data.

[image: acc]

[image: loss]

Comment: Try to not preprocess image before feeding it to the network.

Comment: Accuracy has increased but the result is the same. I mean I just removed "x = preprocess_input(x)"

Comment: Regarding the training: did you use the training code direct from the keras-fcn repository? Because the owner of the repository himself said it needed to be tuned. I have had some success after tuning some things. Also, can you please report your training history (training set loss & accuracy, test set loss & accuracy against epoch number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the problem of classifying everything as background.

I am assuming that the supplied images progress from earlier in the training to later (and are probably from the training set).

Some suggestions:

- Try training initially using a weighted cost function with weights inverse to proportion of labels in the data-set. This should get it past any minima/saddles due to the power of the prior.
- Try playing with regularisation parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question about visualisation of label images. You do not need your own colour-map with imshow. You can use the cmap keyword argument to imshow, and choose a qualitative colour-map.

More reading:

- https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html
- https://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html

Example:

```
plt.imshow(img2, cmap="Set1", interpolation="nearest")
```